# Checkbox value is true but tick is not showing - Android / Java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, checkbox

Basically here I have three(3) checkbox list in three(3) different fragment. When I open the activity, my checkbox in the default fragment display like normal, but the one in different fragment display differently. The value of the checkbox is still true. Below is the image for the checkbox to make things clearer and also my code.

First fragment page:

[image]

Second fragment page:

[image]

Code for setting up the checkbox and its `if condition`

```
private void setCheckBox(ArrayList<DataPrefType> arrayList){
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
        id = i + 1;
        checkBox = new CheckBox(getActivity());
        checkBox.setId(i + 1);
        checkBox.setText(arrayList.get(i).getName());
        checkBox.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        checkBox.setLayoutParams(params);
        checkBox.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        checkBoxLayout.addView(checkBox);

        if(!userPreference.isEmpty() || userPreference != null){
            for(int j = 0; j < userPreference.get(0).getDataPrefTypeArrayList().size(); j++){
                int retrieveId = Integer.parseInt(userPreference.get(0).getDataPrefTypeArrayList().get(j).getId());
                if(checkBox.getId() == retrieveId)
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not the answer but a tip... In your first if-statement you should check first if `userPreference` is null (before `!userPreference.isEmpty()`) and replace the `||` with `&&` so both conditions have to be true

Comment: Alright. Thank you for that tip :)

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. I have 2 different fragments in a tabbed activity, each with checkboxes. I load in data into the checkboxes based in the OnViewCreated. In the second fragment, the true checkboxes are highlighted instead of ticked. I have a feeling its an issue due to the tabbed activity.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue always occurs from the second tab onward. I switched the tab positions, and the problem persisted on the second tab.

Answer (score 13):

The bug with the checkboxes not showing as checked even though isChecked is true is within the animation of the draw.

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354138/8183283). I am posting it here as an answer to make it easier to find and including some extra information about how to call it.

Try calling `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState` on the root view (or parent view of your check boxes). If specifically calling to `checkBox.setChecked(true);` as OP is, call this after. In this question, it would be important to call this after all checkboxes have been added to the parent view. This essentially will draw all drawables in the current state, skipping the animation process.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    View v = getView();
    if(v != null) {
        CheckBox chkYourCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.chkYourCheckBox);
        chkYourCheckBox.setChecked(true); //sometimes this may draw fine, and other times it may not
        //***The important line:
        v.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, its an awesome

Comment: It also works for me when I create my dynamic views in the `onStart()` instead of `onCreateView()`

Answer (score 1):

You can override the Fragment's `setUserVisibleHint()` method and load in the checkboxes there.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser)setCheckBox();
}
```

This is just a workaround, and I don't think its the best way to solve it, but I haven't found anything better yet. This can lead to Null pointer exceptions.

Comment: we can avoid NPE via null checker. always keep null checker before accessing any object

Answer (score 1):

I created this [Kotlin extension property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties) to deal with the problem (obviously only useful if you are writing Kotlin code, not Java)

```
/**
 * Set the state of a checkbox skipping animations.
 */

var CheckBox.checked: Boolean
    get() = isChecked
    set(value) {
        if(isChecked != value) {
            isChecked = value
            jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()
        }
    }
```

Now in my code I write `checkbox_view.checked = true` instead of `checkbox_view.isChecked = true`