# CheckBox setChecked() is not working in background fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-checkbox

In a activity, there is a FragmentViewPager which contains 5 Fragments. 5 Fragments will be created at the same time when starting the activity. If the fragment that do setChecked() isn't the front page when app executes CheckBox setChecked(true), the UI of CheckBox is blank and the value of isChecked() is true.

I found that `notifyViewAccessibilityStateChangedIfNeeded(
AccessibilityEvent.CONTENT_CHANGE_TYPE_UNDEFINED);` in `setChecked(boolean checked)` of android CompoundButton.java. Maybe it can not change the UI when a fragment in background. But How to solve it.

```
if (cls.getIf_allow_to_join().equals("是")) {
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
            } else if (cls.getIf_allow_to_join().equals("否")) {
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
```

This is the setChecked() code of Fragment OnCreateView() in a AsyncTask. And if I set this Fragment as the currentItem when I start the activity, there is no this issue.

Comment: You are most likely missing basic concept, specifically, Model, that is "some other place" to store data. [Have a look at this article](https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-1-model-view-controller-3baecef5f2b6)

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I consider your comment have no associate with my question.

Comment: You can expand the question so we might help you with something more. Add some code..

Comment: Ok, some information has been added.

Comment: @karuao Are you getting an error or it is just not happening ?

Comment: no error, just Android didn't change the UI of CheckBox

Comment: If this check is done in `doInBackground()` then it makes sense that state is not properly updated. How do you assign checkbox instance? Is it relative to Fragment instance? Is it different ID for every fragment? If not, that might also be a cause of the problem.

Comment: This check is done in onPostExecute() that call a callback listener. I assign checkbox in onCreateView() of the fragment. There is no ID for fragment which is managed by a FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: For others running into this problem, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42997873/android-checkboxes-not-checked-correctly-in-viewpager-with-data-binding/48354138#48354138

Answer (score 0):

Please use `AppCompatCheckBox` instead of `CheckBox`.

Check ***android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox***